# Shouldn't indexers work with any input type?

Tags: c#

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx)

> "Indexers do not have to be indexed by an integer value; it is up to
>   you how to define the specific look-up mechanism."

However the code below breaks with an exception

> Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was
>   outside the bounds of the array.

```
using System; 
using System.Linq; 

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string fruits;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            fruits = "Apple,Banana,Cantaloupe";
            Console.WriteLine(fruits['B']);
        }

        public string this[char c] // indexer 
        { 
            get
            {    
              var x=  fruits.Split(',');    
                return x.Select(f => f.StartsWith(c.ToString())).SingleOrDefault().ToString();    
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Shouldn't the code above be able to work with a char index instead of an int index?

Comment: You aren't calling your indexer you are calling `String`'s indexer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your link is referring to indexers that you define yourself:

```
public T this[int i]
```

But you are not using the indexer that you have defined, you are using the indexer of the `string` class, which is defined to take an `int` parameter.

Other classes *are* indexed by other types - for example, `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` is indexed by whatever `TKey` is:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string,int>();
dic["hello"] = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not using your indexer in your example, created a indexer for the class `Program` but you need a indexer on the class `String`.

The reason it still works even though the indexer expects a int is a character is castable to a `int` so in your code you are really doing

```
Console.WriteLine(fruits[((int)'B')]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Main is a static method and you are trying to access a non-static property of the class `Program`. The indexer you defined is not even remotely connected to the `String` class. In order to reference your indexer, you need to:

```
Program program = new Program();
program.fruits = "Bananas";
Console.WriteLine(program['B']);
```

but the code above is a terrible and you should never use such a monstrosity. Instead, declare another class and implement the indexer there;